# Filtering out unwanted native libraries in Fresco

Tags: android, fresco

Looking at generated APK, I can see that Fresco comes with native libraries for some popular image formats. How do I keep only one (e.g. WebP) and exclude the rest?

Note: I'm not talking about CPU architecture, which I already handle using `split`.

Comment: This is not yet supported, but we hope to add it in a future release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fresco now consists of multiple (optional) artifacts and you can select what you need for your app, see http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html